Venn Diagram in R indicating different colour in each Category
I have the following script and it return the following error :
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggVennDiagram)

# Define the tool categories based on the dataframe you provided
tools <- data.frame(
  Tools = c("ANNOVAR", "Ensembl VEP", "SnpEff & SnpSift", "MAGMA", "HaploReg",
            "OpenTargets Genetics", "GWAVA", "VarSome", "InterVar", "FUMA", 
            "VAT", "VAAST 2.0", "VPMBench", "OpenCRAVAT", "FAVORannotator"),
  Exonic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  Intragenic_Non_Exonic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  Intergenic = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)

# Define the tool lists for each category
exonic <- tools$Tools[tools$Exonic == 1]
intragenic_non_exonic <- tools$Tools[tools$Intragenic_Non_Exonic == 1]
intergenic <- tools$Tools[tools$Intergenic == 1]

# Create the Venn diagram data
venn_data <- list(
  Exonic = exonic,
  Intragenic_Non_Exonic = intragenic_non_exonic,
  Intergenic = intergenic
)

# Save the diagram as a jpeg file
jpeg("venn_diagram_tools.jpg", units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 300)

# Create the Venn diagram with different colors
ggVennDiagram(venn_data, label_alpha = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Exonic" = "red", "Intragenic_Non_Exonic" = "green", "Intergenic" = "blue")) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Venn Diagram of Tools by Genomic Regions") +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),       # Remove axis titles
    axis.text = element_blank(),        # Remove axis text
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),       # Remove axis ticks
    panel.grid = element_blank(),       # Remove gridlines
    panel.background = element_blank(), # Remove background
    plot.background = element_blank()   # Remove plot background
  )

# Turn off the device to save the file
dev.off()

The Error:
Error in `scale_fill_manual()`:
! Continuous values supplied to discrete scale.
ℹ Example values: 2, 2, 2, 2, and 2

This has to do with categorical variables, Can you help me how to fix it so in each category of the 3 to have another colour ?
Thank you

Had a look at the source code and there is no easy way to get ggVennDiagram to fill each circle by category. It would be easier to simply use the ggvenn package instead.
Note that there are two packages with the same name so the links to the version used in this reprex are included. First, install ggvenn:
# Either from CRAN
install.packages("ggvenn")

# or the latest version
if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("yanlinlin82/ggvenn")

then:
library(ggvenn) # Loads ggplot

ggvenn(
  venn_data, 
  fill_color = c("#C74A8F", "#F0E442", "#0072B2"),
  stroke_size = 0.5,
  set_name_size = 4,
  fill_alpha = 0.5
)


See the ggvenn GitHub documentation for more details.

Yes i had the same feeling . ggVennDiagram is not proper and doesnt work. This with ggvenn seems to work correct! Thank you !

@user3683485 -  ggVennDiagram does work, it just has a different output that could not be easily adapted to your use case. I do find the ggvenn output easier to interpret though.

The issue with your code is that the ggVennDiagram function does not have direct support for Venn diagram colors as specified through scale_fill_manual.
You can use scale_fill_gradientn() to define multiple colors, including the third one. You can change these colors if necessary
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggVennDiagram)

# Define the tool categories based on the dataframe you provided
tools <- data.frame(
  Tools = c("ANNOVAR", "Ensembl VEP", "SnpEff & SnpSift", "MAGMA", "HaploReg",
            "OpenTargets Genetics", "GWAVA", "VarSome", "InterVar", "FUMA", 
            "VAT", "VAAST 2.0", "VPMBench", "OpenCRAVAT", "FAVORannotator"),
  Exonic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  Intragenic_Non_Exonic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  Intergenic = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
)

# Define the tool lists for each category
exonic <- tools$Tools[tools$Exonic == 1]
intragenic_non_exonic <- tools$Tools[tools$Intragenic_Non_Exonic == 1]
intergenic <- tools$Tools[tools$Intergenic == 1]

# Create the Venn diagram data
venn_data <- list(
  Exonic = exonic,
  Intragenic_Non_Exonic = intragenic_non_exonic,
  Intergenic = intergenic
)
# Save the diagram as a jpeg file
jpeg("venn_diagram_tools.jpg", units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 300)
 
ggVennDiagram(venn_data, label_alpha = 0) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("red", "green", "blue")) +  # Use three colors
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Venn Diagram of Tools by Genomic Regions") +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),       # Remove axis titles
    axis.text = element_blank(),        # Remove axis text
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),       # Remove axis ticks
    panel.grid = element_blank(),       # Remove gridlines
    panel.background = element_blank(), # Remove background
    plot.background = element_blank()   # Remove plot background
  )

# Turn off the device to save the file
dev.off()

And I also attach your chart


I tried already the same with scale_fill_gradientn() but is is not proper. Thank you for your reply
